# What is the purpose of the srcdoc attribute in the iframe tag?

Tags: html, iframe

As far as I understand, the content in `srcdoc` overrides the content in `src`. But since you have to write the content of `srcdoc` yourself, why use the `iframe` at all, instead of just putting down the HTML an calling it a day?

Why do this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my site!</h1>

    <iframe srcdoc="<p>Check out this cool thing that I found on the internet:</p>"></iframe>

    <img src="somethingcool.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead of this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my site!</h1>

    <p>Check out this cool thing that I found on the internet:</p>

    <img src="somethingcool.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```